# MinWidth, MaxWidth, MinHeight, MaxHeight don't have effect for <UserControl>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I'm learning to create WPF application with Caliburn Micro framework.

Following the tutorial on the homepage: [Basic Configuration](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/configuration), I removed the default generated `<Window>` xaml, instead, I have `<UserControl>` xaml and bootstrap it via my `AppBoostrapper`.

Here is the MainView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SmartRenamer.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             MinHeight="300"
             MinWidth="300"
             MaxHeight="500"
             MaxWidth="1000">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Open Folder..." x:Name="OpenFolder"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_About" />
        </Menu>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="500" MaxWidth="1000">
            <StackPanel>
                <DataGrid x:Name="FilesList">

                </DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**The problem is I want to set the `MinWidth, MaxWidth, MinHeight, MaxHeight` for my application, but it seems that those configuration in the `MainWindow.xaml` isn't working.**

Here is the two screenshots, where the window is still can be re-sized out of the defined range:

[image: Very small window]
[image: Very big window]
What am I wrong here?

Comment: Hey! I have exactly the same problem now, do you know now how to fix it?

Comment: Nope :(. I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I've already fixed this, but It was a problem with my code. We handled WinAPI event (WindowProc) - and it this case our window doesnt even take MinWidth and MaxWidth ;)

Answer (score 0):

The width and height properties of an UserControl is set by the container that holds that control. I.e. the DesignWidth and DesignHeigth that are used in the design-time are set in the UserControl but in runtime it uses the values set by the container.

I am not experienced in Caliburn Micro but it seems like you can define the design properties in the bootstrapper:

```
   var settings = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
       { "Height" , 300},
       { "Width"  , 300},
   };

   DisplayRootViewFor<ViewModel>(settings);
```